# ImportError when attempting to use Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

Get the error below when trying to use Seaborn within Juptyer Notebook. Already tried updating packages, can anyone help me out?

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-51c0a6f8c5dc> in <module>
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      3 import numpy as np
----> 4 import seaborn as sns
      5 from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
      6 from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler,PolynomialFeatures

c:\users\User12\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py in <module>
      3 from .utils import *  # noqa: F401,F403
      4 from .palettes import *  # noqa: F401,F403
----> 5 from .relational import *  # noqa: F401,F403
      6 from .regression import *  # noqa: F401,F403
      7 from .categorical import *  # noqa: F401,F403

c:\users\User12\lib\site-packages\seaborn\relational.py in <module>
      6 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      7 
----> 8 from ._core import (
      9     VectorPlotter,
     10 )

c:\users\User12\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_core.py in <module>
     15     share_init_params_with_map,
     16 )
---> 17 from .palettes import (
     18     QUAL_PALETTES,
     19     color_palette,

ImportError: cannot import name 'QUAL_PALETTES'
```

Comment: how did you install? how did you update?

Comment: command prompt.... i uninstalled matplotlib and seaborn then reinstalled

Comment: how? conda? pip? specifically, which commands?

Comment: >>>pip uninstall seaborn, >>>pip install seaborn

Comment: do you have any other environments? python 2 and python 3 installed side by side?

Comment: no i only have python 3

Comment: instead of uninstalling/reinstalling, try upgrading directly in pip

Comment: That worked, thanks!